# angular cli ng serve -o giving exception in browser "Uncaught syntax error: Use of const in strict mode"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i have installed typescript and angular cli latest versions. I did ng new and ng build for new application. After that when i ran "ng serve -o" app is loading in browser but not with the content. When i went to developer tools, it is showing me error as "Uncaught syntax error: Use of const in strict mode". Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Does the `-o` stands for `open`?

Comment: please add config files for more information

Comment: yes... o stands for open